# Is it possible to copy 4 uint8_t into 4 int16 in one instruction?

Tags: c++, bit

I wonder if it is possible to copy four `uint8_t` values stored in one `uint32_t` into proper places in `uint64_t` as fast as possible. I am looking for equivalent of:

```
union
{
  struct {uint8_t a; uint8_t b; uint8_t c; uint8_t d};
  uint32_t whole;
} x32;

 union
{
  struct {int16_t a; int16_t b; int16_t c; int16_t d};
  uint64_t whole;
} x64;

x64.a=x32.a;
x64.b=x32.b;
x64.c=x32.c;
x64.d=x32.d;
```

The problem is: I cannot use MMX/SSE.

Comment: Couldn't you add some padding to the x32 union? What's its source?

Comment: You're code is broken. I guess it is only "pseudo code" to demonstrate what you're doing, but I want to say it though: Instead of two, the union has five alternative representations, of which the four `uint8_t`s are all aligned to the first byte of the `uint32_t`. What you probably meant requires wrapping those four fields in a struct to place them next to each other, resulting in 32 bits, instead of over each other.

Comment: why can't you use SSE? What instruction set are you targeting?

Comment: @leemes Thank you. Now it should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type punning through union does not have support in the C++ standard. Instead, use ors and shifts to compose the value together. Correctness is more important than fast but broken code.

```
uint8_t a,b,c,d;
uint64_t whole;

whole = a | (uint64_t (b) << 1*16) | (uint64_t (c) << 2*16) | (uint64_t (d) << 3*16)
```

Answer (score 2):

No. There's no other way to move the data *and zero-extend it* like you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible, since hardly the hardware would provide such (very specific) assembly instruction.